# Run length encoding function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, encoding, list-comprehension, higher-order-functions

For part of a homework assignment I need to write a function that gives a run length encoding of a list, eg: encode [a, a, b, c, c, c]=[(a, 2), (b, 1), (c, 3)]

I am very nearly done.  The function I have written is this:

```
-- Question #5, part a:
-- Given a list such as [a, a, b, c, c, c] return the length encoding [(a, 2), (b, 1), (c, 3)]
encode :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
encode (x:[]) = []
encode (x:xs) = [(x, length(filter (==x) (x:xs)))]++encode(filter (/=x) (xs))
```

This does produce the correct result, however, after outputting the correct result, throws the following error: `*** Exception: A1-Parmar-Govind.hs:(36,1)-(37,77): Non-exhaustive patterns in function encode`

I feel like I've left no stone unturned trying to solve this error. Help?!

Comment: I don't know why the program crashes, but are you sure the program is correct? I think it will produce wrong results if there are two sequences of a character, because the length will consider all occurrences in the remaining string instead of the current sequence. You could use `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` to fix it.

Comment: @Yogu, I did consider that, but in an email my professor has said he wants it to consider all occurrences rather than just the current sequence.

Comment: This is **not a solution** for **run length encoding**, as the other comments mention, but repeating it in bold.  For the input [a,a,b,c,c,c,a,a], Run length encoding RLE should yield [(a,2),(b,1),(c,3),(a,2)], whereas I think this would yields [(a,4),(b,1),(c,3)], which makes it a _frequency counter_ instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message means that your function `encode` is not considering every single possible case. Think about it this way: what kind of list does this function fail for?

As a bigger hint, try enabling warnings in your code. (Do `:set -Wall` in GHCi.) This will give you a warning if you ever write a function but don't consider all possible cases, and it will even tell you which case you missed! It's very handy.

A side-note about `:set -Wall` if you're curious: `:set` allows you to set *flags* from GHCi. This is equivalent to calling `ghc` with those flags, like `ghc -Wall`. The `-Wall` flag enables all warnings—it has nothing to do with walls!

The convention is that any flags that control warnings in general (as opposed to specific warnings) start with a `W`; it's a sort of primitive namespacing for command line flags. You can also enable and disable individual warnings. It might be interesting to read the GHC [manual page about warnings](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you! It was a very simple fix after that!
to clarify, the base case was changed from (x:[]) to just [] - now it works!